# why my page loads on its own after triggering a function( i'm using plain js)

Tags: javascript

my function works perfectly fine, but i only see the result for 1 second
and then the page loads on its own

i've tried

```
<button onclick="person.generate() return false">generate !</button>
```

```html
<form>
                    <input type="text" id="roastInput" placeholder="put the roast here">
                    <input type="range" id="lvlOfRoast" min="1" max="5">
                    <select id="selector">
                        <option>select the topic</option>
                        <option value="cheap">cheap</option>
                        <option value="ugly">ugly</option>
                        <option value="fat">fat</option>
                        <option value="short">short</option>
                    </select>
                    <button onclick="person.generate()">generate !</button>
                </form>
```

```
var lvlOfRoast = document.getElementById("lvlOfRoast");

var selector = document.getElementById("selector");

var roastInput = document.getElementById("roastInput").value;
```

//                    -------------generate roast-------------

```
class roastGenerator {

  generate(){
    for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
      console.log("this is the " + i + " try" );
    if(lvlOfRoast.value == 1){
      if(selector.options[i].value == "cheap"){
      document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = "it works!!" ;
      break;
    }else {
     console.log("pls choose cheap");

    }
}else{
  window.alert("pls choose 1");
  break;
}
}
};
  randomRoast(obj){
                var keys = Object.keys(obj)
                return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
            };
} // close bracket for the class

var person = new roastGenerator();
```

Comment: What's in `person.generate`?

Comment: The default action of the button within a form is to submit that form, reload is the server's response.

Comment: You're posting the form.  Try setting `type="button"` on the button, and/or just removing the `<form>` element entirely if you're not using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: remove the <form> tags surrounding your controls.

Comment: @mhdHD If the answer provided below helped you in solving your issue, do mark it as the correct answer and upvote it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Your form assumes that the button is a form submit button so whenever the button is clicked, the form attempts to send the data either to what you have specified in the `action` attribute or to the page itself (thus causing the reload) if no `action` attribute is specified or if the `action` attribute doesn't have a value.

Just add `type="button"` to your button element to tell your form that your button is not a submit invoker but just a normal button.

**tldr:** Adding the above attribute `type="button"` will prevent the button click from trying to submit the form data.

```
<button type="button" onclick="person.generate()">generate !</button>
```